# python-social-auth generate 'connect with' link as string

Tags: python, django

I'm using [`social-auth-app-django`](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-app-django) to support logins with social apps.
This code is on a angular-djangorest app, so basically the django doesn't serve the html pages.

Now from the docs, I can see that if I did serve the html pages, I would simply add the following line to generate the 'connect with' link:

```
 <a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'instagram' %}">Login with Instagram</a>
```

but since I don't serve the html myself, I need to supply the angular app the string generated between the `{% %}` myself.

For example

```
def connect_with_instagram(request):
    .
    .
    return HttpResponseRedirect(<the 'connect with' string>)
```

So how can I generate this string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{% url 'social:begin' 'instagram' %}`

in normal django python code would be:

`from django.urls import reverse`
`reverse('social:begin', args=['instagram'])`

ending up like this:

```
from django.urls import reverse

def connect_with_instagram(request):
    .
    .
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('social:begin', args=['instagram']))
```